# Why is it when I change my animation and delete keyframes it deletes keyframes from a different animation?

Tags: animation

I have 4 <strike>animations</strike> actions, idle, walk, run, woodcutting.

I swap between the different <strike>animations</strike> actions to show each of their dope sheets and then I delete the woodcutting keyframes, but in doing so it deletes the idle <strike>animations</strike> action keyframes. Why is that?

[image]

I'm finding it very frustrating learning Blender, any advice would be great. I need to delete the Woodcutting keyframes so I can start over...

How do I delete Actions? I've read the best way to do it is through the NLA editor but there's no right click option when mousing over an action and clicking Delete Strips in the Editor tab doesn't appear to do anything.

I've clicked the + icon 2-too many times, and of course the X icon doesn't delete the active action, it just clears the selection.

Here's a link to the file (and sorry its on Dropbox. Not sure what else to use):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9bh0sh81grjmcy/BlenderSaveShare_UsrAnthony.blend?dl=0

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I've added a link to the file, it's at the bottom of my post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is not what you're describing, actually you're completely misguided because one of your window is completely collapsed, so when you think you're deleting the keyframes of an action you're actually deleting the keyframes of another. So first of all, uncollapse your window, and now you'll see the action that is really selected:

[image]

To delete actions, there are several ways, one is to go to the Outliner, select Blender File in the dropdown menu, unfold the action menu, select and right click Delete. You can also shift click on the X, the action has a 0 in front of its name, meaning that it doesn't have any user anymore, it won't be here when you'll reopen the file. You can't delete actions with the NLA.

[image]

Comment: Ah, alright. I thought I was being clever having a second Dope Sheet window open, letting me swap actions without having to change the window mode. And thanks for explaining how to delete actions.

Comment: you can have a second one, but don't collapse it, otherwise if you select an action you won't be able to see its keyframes   ;)